# What can I eat in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm currently starving at half a heart in a dirt hovel. What can I eat to remedy my problem in this wonderful cubic world?

Basically looking for a list of the various food items in minecraft and what there restorative values are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All food items with their restorative values can be found at [the minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food). In my opinion though, the easiest food items to obtain at the very beginning can be obtained by one of two ways:

1. Killing cows, chickens, or pigs and cooking the meat in a furnace
2. Finding the two varieties of mushrooms (brown and red) and making mushroom stew. Brown mushrooms can be found just about anywhere. Red are typically a bit more difficult to find, but both can be found fairly often on the surface.

Comment: Mushrooms are common in the new swamp biome.

Comment: And even more common with the new forest type that has giant mushrooms in them (along with the mushroom biome, but those are rare).

Answer (score 5):

The entire list of  restorative values are [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food).

and you shouldn't die unless you are on hard because the minecraft wiki page on [hunger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger) states:

> If you have 90%-100% food you will regain health slowly, but if you have 0% you will lose health instead. On easy the player's health would slowly drop to 5 hearts, 0.5 hearts on normal, and all the way to death on hard